# How to automatically reduce height of all other table rows when one table row's height is increased?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am creating a 3x3 grid of images using html tables. I want to increase both the width and height of an image when the cursor is over that particular image. Now, when i increase the width of one table cell, the width of all other table cells in that particular row automatically gets reduced. Unfortunately, when i increase the height of a table cell, the height of the table cells below it remains the same causing the table itself to increase in height.

How to cause the height of other cells to get reduced automatically?

Comment: you need to share your relevant code and make a working example of your specific problem

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using flexbox instead of html tables?
You can set custom flex-grow and flex-shrink parameters to achieve what you want.

You can read more about it there: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to increase width and height when cursor is over image. Than you need to increase width and/or height only on hover, not for all cases.